# Define N to be the number of rolls required of a fair die to observe 2nd 6

Tags: probability

I'm having difficulty understanding the solution to this problem.

```
Define N to be the number of rolls required of a fair die to observe 2nd 6
Example: If the rolls are ( 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 6) then N = 6

Find probability N = 13
```

Solution

```
P(N=13) = [12 * (5/6)^11 * (1/6)](1/6)
```

Why there a 12? I understand that each roll is independent, thus you can multiply each event. But I'm not quite understanding how the 12 was derived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from a binomial distribution expression. $P(13)$ is the probability of getting exactly one 6 in 12 rolls, then getting the second one on the 13th roll. What's the probability of getting a single 6 in 12 rolls of the dice? Well, if $X \sim Bin(\frac{1}{6}, 12)$ then $P(X = 1) = {12 \choose 1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^1\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{11}=12\times\frac{1}{6}\times\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{11}$.

On the off-chance you haven't covered the binomial distribution yet, then it's the product of the probabilities of the individual rolls (of one 6 and eleven not-6s), multiplied by the number of arrangements of those rolls (because the 6 could be in any of 12 equivalent places in the order of the rolls).

Then you just multiply by another $\frac{1}{6}$ to represent the 13th roll.